# Are zk (zero knowledge) blockchains private?

Tags: zero-knowledge, zksync

I've been seeing all this information around zero-knowledge blockchains or layer twos like [zkSync](https://zksync.io/).

Is my information private on these chains/L2s?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

In the case of [zkSync](https://zksync.io/), the "zero knowledge" aspect of the chain refers specifically to the way the data is rolled up. ZkSync uses a "zero-knowledge proof" to send a bunch of transactions from it's L2 -> the L1 (Ethereum), but the chain itself has public data.

There are some chains like [aztec](https://aztec.network/) that are working on a layer two that is fully private.

### Summary

A "zk chain" doesn't necessarily mean that the blockchain is private, it's often a shorthand way of referring to how the transactions are rolled up to the L1.

To learn more about L1s vs L2s, you can [read here.](https://chain.link/education-hub/what-is-layer-2)